# Why do I have 70k instances of ck-get-x11-server-pid running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server which currently has 69890 instances of `ck-get-x11-server-pid` running. The server is headless, but users can login to a using x2go.

Why would there be so many instances of `ck-get-x11-server-pid`, and can I safely `killall ck-get-x11-server-pid`?